# forEach with $http.get how to handle when request stays pending and never returns

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my first time using angular so very sorry about the bad codding.

**Problem:** I have an $http.get inside a forEach loop which gets data from a WebApi. This works fine until some of the calls stay pending and never get a return call. How can I write some logic to handle when a call stays pending ?

[image: Network Picture]

Hourly.js

```
         $http.get('http://localhost:52332/api/HourlySummary/?' + 'div=' + divarg + '&line='+ i.line)                       
                .then(function (response) {
                         console.log('http then ', i.line);                             
                         count++;
                         if (i.line == 'S') {
                             storeS.valuesS = response.data;                                 
                             $scope.date = Date.now();
                         } else if (i.line == 'M') {
                             storeM.valuesM = response.data;                                 
                             $scope.date = Date.now();
                         } else if (i.line == 'L') {
                             storeL.valuesL = response.data;                                 
                             $scope.date = Date.now();                                 
                         }

                         if (count == 3) {
                             myLoop();
                         }
                     }, function (response) {
                         console.log("Somehting went wrong ", i.line);
                     });
```

Comment: You need to reduce the code to zero in on the problem. See: [mcve]

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Its my question a little bit better ? . Can you help me with my question ? I would really appreciated.

Comment: It's probably better to discover the root cause of the pending than writing lines of JS to work around - what I guess is a local server misbehaving. The server should ideally should return some sort of result or timeout.

Comment: You need to determine why that is happening in the api call and fix it. Also, you mentioned that you have a http.get inside a forEach loop. It would be better if you could call out to an api only 1 time to get all the data you need by passing params.

Comment: @PeterS and mlhuff. Thank you so much for the advices. I'm Trying to find out what is causing the issue on the Web API. I really appreciate the positive feedback !

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timeout on the request:

```
$http.get('/urlpath/', { timeout: 10000 })   // wait 10 seconds
```

I *think* that puts a status code of -1 in the response.